# Does choices of 0 & 1 after data standardization affect learning result of convolutional neural network?

Tags: conv-neural-network

I come across this question in my mind when I am building an image quality enhancing CNN. Let's say my target image has a subject that needs to be enhanced and a background that should stay the same after passing the network. I intuitively think 0s should be assigned for the background so that in forward propagation, the influence of kernels is minimized when passing the pixels at background. In this way, the background is more likely to stay the same even after the CNN. However, when I think about the backpropagation, I can't explain to myself this is true mathematically. At the same time, some also suggests using data range from -1 to 1 to amplify the data difference for better network learning. I am thinking is this '0 for background' strategy really a better method to differentiate the subject and the background? I rememeber I saw some theories similar online but I just can't phrase my problem good enough to find it. Any help would be appreciated! Thx